How to execute Pagination in firebase or react query
i'm trying to paginate my products from my firebase firestore but the products are not loding its returning null or undefined
here is my state context i just dont seem to get it right
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  

  const initialState = {
    showCart: false,
    products: items,
    cartItems: c,
  };
  const { q } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["products"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const first = query(
        collection(db, "products"),
        orderBy("title"),
        limit(4)
      );
      const data = await getDocs(first);
      data.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        let key = doc.id;
        let item = doc.data();
        // items.push({ key, item });
      });
      setItems(data.docs);
      console.log(data.docs.lenght);
    },
  
// output in console: 0

// expected File;[{...}] array object
});


So if you console.log(data.docs.length) is prints 0? If so, can you add that code, and its output to the question? Then, can you show a screenshot of a document that you expect to be returned by the query?

yes it returns 0 can,t get the screen shot tho

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Without seeing a document that you expect to be returned, it's hard to say why the query isn't returning it.

I have fixed it. The collection reference was wrong, so it did not find the Firestore reference and returned null or undefined.
Here is the fix:
{
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["products"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const first = query(
        collection(db, "products"),
        //collectio reference folder is suppose to be 
        'Products' not 'products'
        orderBy("title"),
        limit(4)
      );
      const data = await getDocs(first);
      data.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        let key = doc.id;
        let item = doc.data();
        items.push({ key, item });
      });
      setItems(data.docs);
    },
  });
}

